# No Laravel Sessions for Bots

Tags: laravel, session, redis, bots

I'm having problems with a big Laravel project and the Redis storage. We store our sessions in Redis. We already have 28GB of RAM there. However, it still runs relatively fast to the limit, because we have very many hits (more than 250,000 per day) from search engine bots.

Is there any elegant way to completely disable sessions for bots? I have already implemented my own session middleware, which looks like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use App\Custom\System\Visitor;

class StartSession extends \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession
{
    protected function getSessionLifetimeInSeconds()
    {
        if(Visitor::isBot()) {
            return 1;
        }

        return ($this->manager->getSessionConfig()['lifetime'] ?? null) * 60;
    }

    protected function sessionIsPersistent(array $config = null)
    {
        if(Visitor::isBot()) {
            return false;
        }

        $config = $config ?: $this->manager->getSessionConfig();

        return ! in_array($config['driver'], [null, 'array']);
    }
}
```

This is my function for detecting bots:

```
public static function isBot()
    {
        $exceptUserAgents = [
            'Googlebot',
            'Bingbot',
            'Yahoo! Slurp',
            'DuckDuckBot',
            'Baiduspider',
            'YandexBot',
            'Sogou',
            'facebot',
            'ia_archiver',
        ];

        if(!request()->header('User-Agent') || !str_contains(request()->header('User-Agent'), $exceptUserAgents)) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Unfortunately, this does not seem to work. Does anyone have a tip or experience here? Thank you very much!

Comment: 250,000 page views per day is around 3 page views per second, which is a very small amount and if you're requiring 28GB of ram just to support sessions alone, it's indicative of serious issues with your application design. That's 100kb of storage *per request*. I will post an answer to your question, but it's certainly worth investigating the efficiency and design of your application if you're experiencing this problem. I run a Laravel application that supports often has 10 requests per second, and that's ran from a single server with 1GB of ram, and has lots of room to grow.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is how I solved this for myself.

1. Include a bot detection package using composer. I used this one: https://github.com/JayBizzle/Crawler-Detect

   `composer require jaybizzle/crawler-detect`
2. Create a new middleware class

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

class NoSessionForBotsMiddleware
{
    public function handle($request, \Closure $next)
    {
        if ((new \Jaybizzle\CrawlerDetect\CrawlerDetect)->isCrawler()) {
            \Config::set('session.driver', 'array');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

3. Register the middleware *before* session middleware in the `Kernel` class:

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        // ..
        NoSessionForBotsMiddleware::class,
        StartSession::class,
        // ..
    ],
    // ..
];
```

Comment: Very neat solution! I used the same approach to avoid creating the sessions for load balancer health check requests.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem could be that you're not identifying robots correctly, so it would be helpful to provide the code for that.

Specific to writing middleware that disables sessions, you're much better off changing the session driver to the `array` driver as that driver does not persist sessions, instead of changing the configuration of the real session driver at runtime.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use App\Custom\System\Visitor;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config;

class DiscardSessionIfBot
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (Visitor::isBot()) {
            Config::set('session.driver', 'array');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```