# Laravel Session Database Driver freezes database randomly

Tags: laravel

Running laravel 5.4 using DB sessions driver. Randomly I have thousands of

```
update `sessions` set `payload` where id ....
```

when viewing the process list via mysql.

Seems like Laravel decides to update tons of sessions suddenly, causing the whole database to become unresponsive (DB running on dedicated server) and the max connections gets filled up pretty quick. I have a long session lifetime (as I don't want to log out the users) and in result the sessions table is quite huge.

I tried to limit the lottery to 0, 100 in case that would have been causing the issue but it has not helped.

Any ideas what could cause this / what I could try?

sessions table is INNODB, indexes in id and user_id

Comment: Can you provide your full query? There must be something that triggers all column to update.

Comment: As it seems to be done by laravel, I really don't have the query which causes this :). Only thing I can see from the processlist is tons of: update `sessions` set `payload` = 'payloadhere', `last_activity` = unixtime, `user_id` = userid, `ip_address` = 'userip', `user_agent` = 'useragentinfo' where `id` = 'idhere'

Comment: According to your question, i have yet to experience this issue so far but i can suggest a few optimization hope it helps. Create a cron to check user last activity and eliminate some sessions and ensure one session only per user. While waiting a better answer ><

Comment: One session per user sounds like a great idea! Thanks.

Comment: As the query above update by user_id means without eliminating the old session a lot of updates will be done. Glad it helps to optimize something first~ ^^

Comment: It's not actually where "userid" but instead ID field which is a string in laravel. ..indexed that as well but naturally not the best solution. I'm thinking about setting up a dedicated remote redis server and having it to handle the sessions instead of using database for it.

Comment: Might be caused by usual crawler bots? Check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51176946/no-laravel-sessions-for-bots

Comment: @MihirBhende Thanks! Very likely, I will try it out

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue last week.

Your mind blows because you really don't know what is going on or even worse: *what it's causing this issue*.

I was using the database session drive for nearly 2 years and this situation never happened before.

The solution was to change the session drive to REDIS.

In `config/session.php` change the **connection** key:

```
 'connection' => 'session'
```

In `config/database.php` add the following lines on redis entry:

```
'redis' => [

    'cluster' => false,

    'default' => [
        'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
        'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
        'database' => 0,
    ],

    'session' => [
        'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
        'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
        'database' => 1,
    ],

],
```

The reason to add one more entry 'session' is:

- If you run:

`php artisan cache:clear`

**ALL OF YOUR SESSIONS WILL BE CLEARED TOO**, not only the cache itself.

So, to avoid that, just add this new entry.

You can find more info here:

[Redis As Session Driver With Laravel](https://paulund.co.uk/problem-using-redis-session-driver)

Comment: Sorry but that's  not the solution. There's various reasons to use DB instead of Redis / File Cache / Cookie in different situations. However my findings: Not Indexed properly and searched made based to text field are the cause on busy site.  I dealt this by switching to cookies myself as even optimizing the session table didn't help enough.

Comment: In the internet I found that REDIS is the best option to deal with sessions. REDIS is an In-Memory Database (IMDB) while Database uses disk storage mechanism. In a website or app with high traffic the Database driver will use a lot of (I/O) and the resources could get filled quickly. In my case the response time got 37ms faster with REDIS. You can use REDIS to scale your application as same as Database do. Give it a try :)

Comment: Yes I've long gone from DB :). However, problem with Redis is that if you're running multi server setup it gets tricky. I did not find a proper safe and reliable way for that so I went for cookies instead.